# What is the best way to ping the url so that the server have the minimum possible load

Tags: php, curl, ping

I'm looking to ping a lot of URL's without caring about the output, what I care about is performance, I want to know what is the best way of doing so

Comment: What do you mean by "ping"?  Are you actually trying to ping a host?  Or request the headers of a resource at a particular URL?

Comment: `without caring about the output` - surely you must care about *something* to do with the output? Surely you must want to know whether packets are returned? Or are you trying to implement a ping-of-death, because I doubt you'll find anyone here who'll help you with that. Well, I hope not, anyway.

Comment: Are you so specific to use `php`? Coz there are load testing tools which will suits this requirement. http://learnloadrunner.com/

Comment: Well if what you want to do is get the headers for many URLs at the same time, [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) is what you are looking for. But I agree with @sundar that PHP is not the best language for this, Node.js springs immediately to mind as being very easy to implement this sort of thing with.

Comment: @DaveRandom no I'm really not caring about the output, I just want to execute the URL until it finish executing

Comment: can curl_milti_exec() execute a URL till it's death?

Comment: Until its death? Are you planning to kill websites?

Comment: @sundar I'm specific to PHP, also I never used node.js and don't know how to run it

Comment: @SanjanaThakur `curl_multi_exec()` executes a set of cURL handles all at the same time. By `till it's death` I presume you mean "until the HTTP transaction is complete", in which case the answer is "Yes" (that's sort of the point of it).

Comment: @MathieuImbert nope :D what I meant it the execution of the script must finish

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155512/using-php-to-ping-a-website) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php) answers.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks this will do the job I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP HEAD request is probably what you are looking for. It will return you full information about particular URL (status code, size, etc ...) but without transferring its contents. This request can be made with any 'low-level' TCP functions like PHP's fsockopen and CURL extension, shell's telnet and similar.